# Custom Post type registering as page post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I'm having trouble getting my custom post type to correctly register. It seems to be identifying as a page post type and using that template. I also can't access the archive page for it. Any idea on what's wrong?

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_women' );

function register_cpt_women() {

    $womenLabels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'The Women', 'women' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'The Women', 'women' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'women' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Woman', 'women' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Woman', 'women' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Woman', 'women' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Woman', 'women' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Women', 'women' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No women found', 'women' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No women found in Trash', 'women' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Woman:', 'women' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'The Women', 'women' ),
    );

    $womenArgs = array( 
        'labels' => $womenLabels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'The Women Listing',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'menu_icon' => '/wp-content/themes/ssekoDesigns/assets/img/ico-jobs.png',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'women', $womenArgs );

}
```

Comment: I believe you need to make seperate templates for each display type for the new post type, like a post type of women would need a women-single.php in order to view single listings of the women cpt. You may also need archive and other templates such as women-archive.php in order for the archive display to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings>Permalinks and re-save your permalinks. When you initialize a post type you need to refresh your rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?php
/* Testimonial */
function dyn_testimonial_post_tipe() {
    register_post_type( 'testimonial',
                array( 
                'label' => __('Testimonial'), 
                'singular_label' => __('testimonial Name'),
                '_builtin' => false,
                'public' => true, 
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'page',
                'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/post-tipe/icon/testimonial.png',
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'testimonial-view',
                    'with_front' => FALSE,
                ),
                'supports' => array(
                        'title',
                        'editor',
                        'thumbnail')
                        ) 
                );
    register_taxonomy('testimonial_category', 'testimonial', 
        array(
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'label' => 'Testimonial Categories', 
        'singular_name' => 'Category', 
        "rewrite" => true, 
        "query_var" => true));
}
add_action('init', 'dyn_testimonial_post_tipe');
    // Add to admin_init function
    add_action('manage_testimonial_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_testimonial_columns', 10, 2);
    add_filter('manage_edit-testimonial_columns', 'my_testimonial_columns');
    //Add columns for Testimonial posts
function my_testimonial_columns($columns) {
    $columns = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "title" => "Title",
        "testimonial_categories" => "Categories",
        "comments" => "<span><span class=\"vers\"><img src=\"".get_admin_url()."images/comment-grey-bubble.png\" alt=\"Comments\"></span></span>",
        "date" => "Date",

    );
    return $columns;
}
function custom_testimonial_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
    case 'testimonial_categories':
        $terms = get_the_term_list( $post_id , 'testimonial_category' , '' , ',' , '' );
        if ( is_string( $terms ) ) {
            echo $terms;
        } else {
            echo 'Uncategorized';
        }
        break;
    }
}
?>
```